# whileの中でTypeErrorが出て処理が進まないのを解決したい

Tags: python

半加算と全加算を用いた２進数の計算を行いたいのですが,最後のwhile構文から下でエラーが表示され処理が進みません。どなたかご教示お願いします

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1544c3673a72> in <module>
     39 goukei = ""
     40 while k >= 0:
---> 41   ha = int(a(k))
     42   fa = int(b(k))
     43   A,keta = fa(a,b,x)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**コード:**

```py
from traitlets.config.application import logging
def AND(a,b):
  A = a * b
  return A
 
def OR(a,b):
   if a==1:
     if b==1:
        A=1
     else:
        A=0

def NOT(a):
  if a==1:
    A=0
  if a==0:
    A=1
  return A

def ha(a,b):
    A1 = OR(a,b)
    keta = AND(a,b)
    A2 = NOT(keta)
    A = AND(A1,A2)
    return A,keta

def fa(a,b,x):
  A1,keta1 = ha(a,b)
  A,keta2 = ha(A1,x)
  keta = OR(keta1,keta2)
  return A,keta

a = input("2進数の数字")
b = input("2進数に足す方")
k = len(a)
k = k - 1
x = 0
goukei = ""
while k >= 0:
  ha = int(a(k))
  fa = int(b(k))
  A,keta = fa(a,b,x)
  goukei = str(A) + goukei
  x = keta
  k = k - 1
  goukei = str(x) + goukei
  print(a,"+",b,"=",goukei)
```

Comment: 色々と複数の問題が見受けられますが、おそらくこの記事の回答内容と類似しています。[Python、プログラミングの問題です。...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12252234857) 参考にしてください。

Comment: もしも解決したのなら [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考に。未解決部分があるなら(この質問の範囲で) 質問に追記してください

Answer (score 2):

処理全体としては, 大きく 3箇所ほどの間違いがあり

1. `OR` 関数が結果を返していない。そもそも判定が間違ってそう
2. bit 文字列から要素取り出す指定が違う (後述)
3. (元の記述のままのはずだが) インデントが違う。`goukei = str(x) + goukei` 以下はループの外のはず

要素の取り出し部分

```py
while k >= 0:
  ha = int(a(k))
  fa = int(b(k))
  A,keta = fa(a,b,x)
```

取り出すなら **`a[k]`**, **`b[k]`** のはずで

- `ha`, `fa` は関数名として使用しているので上書きしてしまう。別の変数名にすべき
- 関数 `fa` に指定する値は, `a`, `b` ではなく, 直前の「取り出した値」のはず

Answer (score 0):

既に回答された方の指摘の修正と `a` と `b` の桁数が異なる場合でも計算できるようにしました。なお，`0` で埋めて同じ桁数にしてから計算する方法もあります。

```
def AND(x, y):
    return 1 if x and y else 0

def OR(x, y):
    return 1 if x or y else 0

def NOT(x):
    return 1 if not x else 0

def ha(x, y):
    K = AND(x, y)
    A = AND(OR(x, y), NOT(K))
    return A, K

def fa(x, y, z):
    A1, K1 = ha(x, y)
    A2, K2 = ha(A1, z)
    K3 = OR(K1, K2)
    return A2, K3


a = input("2進数a: ")
b = input("2進数b: ")

k, m = len(a), len(b)
keta = 0
goukei = ''
while k > 0 or m > 0:
    k, m = k - 1, m - 1
    na = 0 if k < 0 else int(a[k])
    nb = 0 if m < 0 else int(b[m])
    ns, keta = fa(na, nb, keta)
    goukei = str(ns) + goukei

goukei = ('1' if keta else '') + goukei
print(f'{a} + {b} = {goukei}')
```

```
2進数a: 110011
2進数b: 1110
110011 + 1110 = 1000001
```